# Getting the current background id of a view

Tags: android, android-layout, drawable

I have a Layout with a background defined in drawable, and i want to change it under some conditions to another. How do i get the identifier of the current background to know what it is?

Comment: you should set `id` for layout which is current, then declare it incode by `findviewbyid` and then by this declariation you will be able change background

Comment: the question is interesting, but i don't see the use case ?

Answer (score 12):

This may be a very old question, but just in case if people still looking for it:

```
if(yourView.getBackground().getConstantState().equals(
    getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.yourdrawable).getConstantState()){

  //do something if this is the correct drawable
}
```

Be reminded to check for null. In some cases, `yourView.getBackground()` can return null if the source is vector drawable.

Answer (score 3):

Hi you can try this example,

```
btnNew =(Button)findViewById(R.id.newButton); 

 // compare newlist
if(newButton.getBackground()!=(findViewById(R.id.imgAdd)).getBackground()) 
{ 
   btnNew.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.imgDelete); 
}
```

Comment: -1 for `findViewById(R.drawable.imgAdd)` (find by id with a drawable ref, which returns null.

Comment: i wrote it just here without using editor. Anyway i edited my answer. Thanx for your -1 :)

Answer (score 1):

you can try by this way.

Assign id to layout which you want to change background as per condition. and do like this

```
            linear1 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.bg_l_l);

        if(condition==true)
        {
            linear1.setBackgroundDrawable(R.drawable.sample_thumb_0);
        }
        else if (condition2==true)
        {
            linear1.setBackgroundDrawable(R.drawable.sample_thumb_1);
        }
        else
        {
            linear1.setBackgroundDrawable(R.drawable.sample_thumb_2);
        }
```

Comment: What is condition, he want to compare drawables

Comment: as questioner told that he wants to change as per the condition. so that he will be decide that what should be condition.

Comment: He wants to compare drawables, thats why he asked the condition

Comment: thanks for guide me.as per my understanding of above query i have replied to him. you can update if you want.:)

Answer (score 1):

You can simply get the whole `Drawable` by `Drawable beforeClickDrawalbe=view.getBackground();`

and change the background of your view by doing: `view.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.YOUR_DRAWABLE));`

and then if you want to set it back to the initial background you don't need the id 
because you have the whole Drawable so do:
`view.setBackgroundDrawable(beforeClickDrawalbe));`

That's all!